# Documentation of /system/addon.d

Tags: twrp, ota-update, system

Placing scripts into `/system/addon.d/` makes them execute before and after every OTA packag upgrade.
[This](https://www.reddit.com/r/LineageOS/comments/7lndos/what_is_the_naming_convention_of_addond_script/)
[is](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/202350/how-to-write-a-script-that-removes-a-certain-set-of-apps-everytime-you-flash-an)
[used](https://gitlab.com/fdroid/privileged-extension/-/blob/master/app/src/main/scripts/80-fdroid.sh)
[or](https://github.com/topjohnwu/Magisk/blob/master/scripts/addon.d.sh)
[mentioned](https://forum.xda-developers.com/nexus-4/development/mod-silent-camera-t2061692)
[in](https://appuals.com/how-to-create-a-flashable-zip-for-android-system-mods/)
[multiple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52288668/android-addon-d-script-not-running-properly)
[places](https://gitlab.com/kalilinux/nethunter/build-scripts/kali-nethunter-project/blob/d2cd3ea4cd511981cc892df9ee367167edaf40d6/nethunter-installer/update/system/addon.d/80-nethunter.sh).

I have multiple questions about this:

- Is this a general Android feature or just provided by many custom ROMs? If only ROMs, any notable exceptions?
- Where is the documentation / specification / source ? I would like to get to the APIs that I can work with.
- (related) What is it with this `/tmp/backuptool.functions` that seemingly anyone is sourcing at the beginning of the script. How could I find out which functions are provided by this and what they do?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a standard, but just a convention which is followed by many in custom ROM world. IIRC it's the LineageOS/CM who [introduced](https://github.com/LineageOS/android_vendor_lineage/commit/b1637c8e2b8c81ec469b303fa65b0a2612be3ae0) the idea. So their [repo](https://github.com/LineageOS/android_vendor_lineage/tree/lineage-18.0/prebuilt/common/bin) is the best place to see latest changes.

There is no complicated API, just a few bash script functions to backup/restore some files during OTAs (dirty flashes).